# Style specific text in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to style differently the properties "fonction" and "nom" but I really don't know where to start. I probably won't need any specific style for "fonction" but, for "nom", I'd like to have the text bold and with the same color than the property "type".

```
{    
  "fonction": "blah1",
  "nom": "wah1",
  "type": "green", 
  "level": "green"
},   
{    
  "fonction": "blah2",
  "nom": "wah2",
  "type": "yellow", 
  "level": "yellow"
}
```

Here is part of the code used to append text:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + 
           "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on("click", click);
           nodeEnter.append("circle")  
          .attr("r", function(d) { return d.value; })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.type; })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d.level; });

          nodeEnter.append("text")
         .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; 
         })
         .attr("dy", ".35em")
         .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 
         "end" : "start"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d.fonction + " " + d.nom; })
         .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

I use here the code used for another question I asked here so they won't be mixed.

Can't find a way to tell D3 to style only "nom" as both properties have the "text" type. I'd be very grateful for some directions to look into.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply different styles to different texts, you cannot append them using the same `text()` method, as you're doing:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.fonction + " " + d.nom; })
```

You have to separate them. For instance, using a `<span>`:

```
.text(function(d){ return d.fonction + " ";})
.append("span")
.text(function(d){ return d.nom;});
```

Here is a very simple demo using your data array:

```js
var data = [{
  "fonction": "blah1",
  "nom": "wah1",
  "type": "green",
  "level": "green"
}, {
  "fonction": "blah2",
  "nom": "wah2",
  "type": "yellow",
  "level": "yellow"
}];

d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .style("color", "red")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.fonction + " ";
  })
  .append("span")
  .style("color", "blue")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.nom;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -180 : 40; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      //.append("p")
      .text(function(d) {return d.fonction + " "; })
      .append("p")
      .text(function(d) {return d.nom;});

Comment: what does that comment mean?

Comment: Thanks. I understand the code and it does what I need but I can't integrate it with mine. Thanks. If I try to append the paragraph, all the labels dissapear (and the span appears but doesn't show) nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -180 : 40; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })

Comment: You cannot append a paragraph to an SVG. My snippet was only an example showing you how to break the text. You have to append a **tspan**.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using CSS and test the data to determine which class to add dynamically. Something like:

```
newEvent.append("text")
    .attr('y', 5)
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
        // this will color all the 'odd' numbered
        // text elements "blue"
        if (i % 2 == 0){
             return "event-text"
         } else {
             return "event-text-blue"
         }
     })
     .text(function (d) {
         return d.eventText
     });
```

Don't know if that is the "best" way but it works.

### CSS

```
.event-text {
    fill: white;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.event-text-blue {
    fill: blue;
    text-shadow: 3px 2px gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Clever idea even if I ended using the other answer. Thks!